# Visualizing Brainf_ck interpreter in ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, brainfuck

I have written a working Brainfuck interpreter using ClojureScript, reagent, core.async and dommy. I am not very satisfied with the code, however, in particular the central part of the code - the interpreting function, `step`. It is a pages-long mess of nested conditionals. I would like to simplify it somehow. One thing I'm considering is to seperate the "leaf" parts of the conditional tree into smaller functions, and thus trim the tree, creating a more clear overview. But even if I did so, I feel that the tree would still be too big or complex. I feel like the problem lies in my need to check for looping before "normal" interpreting conditions in the `condp`, (which is pretty good by itself, I feel), but I don't currently see how to avoid this structure - if I remove the pre-`condp` loop checks, I would need to add the checks to every `condp` leaf, and that does not seem like a better alternative.

I've considered using a state machine library such as https://github.com/cdorrat/reduce-fsm , but I fear that the use of non-core conditional structures would do as much harm in their "unusualness" as they would do good in their clearer structures, evening out pros and cons with the "bonus" of an added dependency.

I'm currently keeping all the code in one file, because I find it easier to navigate that way, but I will separate the functionality into different namespaces eventually.

If you feel like running the code, check it out at https://github.com/Reefersleep/derpanet . You can view the running code at https://derpanet.herokuapp.com/
It's best in Firefox, wonky but workable in Chrome, and while non-essential functionality (the sliders) is broken in IE, the interpreting functionality still works.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

*EDIT*: Added link to running application.

```clj
(ns ^:figwheel-always derpanet.core
  (:require [reagent.core :as r]
            [figwheel.client :as fw :include-macros true]
            [cljs.core.async :refer [>! <! chan buffer close!
                                     alts!  timeout]]
            [dommy.core :refer-macros [sel1]])
  (:require-macros
   [cljs.core.async.macros :as m :refer [go]]))


(defn number-box [number text-color box-size]
  [:div {:style {:border-color "black"
                 :border-style "solid"
                 :border-width "1px"
                 :min-width (str box-size "px")
                 :min-height (str box-size "px")
                 :position "relative"
                 :color text-color}}
   [:div {:style {:position "absolute"
                  :top "50%"
                  :left "50%"
                  :transform "translate(-50%, -50%)"
                  }} (str number)]])

(def input-buffer (chan 1))

;; Interpreter start ---------------------------------------------
(defn initialize-cells [number] (vec (repeat number 0)))

(defn out-of-upper-sourcecode-bounds? [interpreter-state]
  (= (:reader-position interpreter-state) (count (:src interpreter-state)))) ;;TODO currently only checks for upper bounds

(defn retrieve-current-symbol [interpreter-state]
  (nth (:src interpreter-state) (:reader-position interpreter-state)))

(defn looping-forward? [interpreter-state]
  (= :looping-forward (:movement interpreter-state)))

(defn brackets-balanced? [interpreter-state]
  (= (:nested-left-brackets interpreter-state) (:nested-right-brackets interpreter-state)))

(defn looping-backward? [interpreter-state]
  (= :looping-backward (:movement interpreter-state)))

(defn step [interpreter-state input-chan current-symbol text-input]
  (let [{:keys [src
                reader-position
                cells
                cell-pointer
                movement
                nested-left-brackets
                nested-right-brackets]} interpreter-state]
    (if (out-of-upper-sourcecode-bounds? interpreter-state)
      (assoc interpreter-state :terminated-due-to :reached-upper-sourcecode-bounds)
      (cond
        (looping-forward? interpreter-state) (if (= \] current-symbol)
                                               (if (brackets-balanced? interpreter-state)
                                                 ;; stop looping and start moving forward normally - reset nested brackets
                                                 (assoc interpreter-state
                                                        :reader-position (inc reader-position)
                                                        :movement :moving-forward
                                                        :nested-left-brackets 0
                                                        :nested-right-brackets 0)
                                                 ;; continue looping and add nested right bracket
                                                 (assoc interpreter-state
                                                        :reader-position (inc reader-position)
                                                        :movement :looping-forward
                                                        :nested-right-brackets (inc nested-right-brackets)))
                                               (if (= \[ current-symbol)
                                                 ;; continue looping and add nested left bracket
                                                 (assoc interpreter-state
                                                        :reader-position (inc reader-position)
                                                        :movement :looping-forward
                                                        :nested-left-brackets (inc nested-left-brackets))
                                                 ;; continue looping
                                                 (assoc interpreter-state 
                                                        :reader-position (inc reader-position)
                                                        :movement :looping-forward)))
        (looping-backward? interpreter-state) (if (= \[ current-symbol)
                                                (if (brackets-balanced? interpreter-state)
                                                  ;; stop looping and start moving forward normally - reset nested brackets
                                                  (assoc interpreter-state
                                                         :reader-position (inc reader-position) 
                                                         :movement :moving-forward
                                                         :nested-left-brackets 0
                                                         :nested-right-brackets 0)
                                                  ;; continue looping and add nested left bracket
                                                  (assoc interpreter-state
                                                         :reader-position (dec reader-position)
                                                         :movement :looping-backward
                                                         :nested-left-brackets (inc nested-left-brackets)))
                                                (if (= \] current-symbol)
                                                  ;; continue looping and add nested right bracket
                                                  (assoc interpreter-state
                                                         :reader-position (dec reader-position)
                                                         :movement :looping-backward
                                                         :nested-right-brackets (inc nested-right-brackets))
                                                  ;; continue looping
                                                  (assoc interpreter-state
                                                         :reader-position (dec reader-position)
                                                         :movement :looping-backward)))
        :else (condp = current-symbol
                \+ (assoc interpreter-state
                          :reader-position (inc reader-position)
                          :cells (assoc cells cell-pointer (inc (nth cells cell-pointer)))
                          :movement :moving-forward)
                \- (assoc interpreter-state
                          :reader-position (inc reader-position)
                          :cells (assoc cells cell-pointer (dec (nth cells cell-pointer)))
                          :movement :moving-forward)
                \> (assoc interpreter-state
                          :reader-position (inc reader-position)
                          :cell-pointer (inc cell-pointer)
                          :movement :moving-forward)
                \<  (assoc interpreter-state
                           :reader-position (inc reader-position)
                           :cell-pointer (dec cell-pointer)
                           :movement :moving-forward)
                \. (assoc interpreter-state
                          :reader-position (inc reader-position)
                          :movement :moving-forward
                          :printedchars (apply str (:printedchars interpreter-state) (char (nth cells cell-pointer))))
                \[ (if (= 0 (nth cells cell-pointer))
                     (assoc interpreter-state
                            :reader-position (inc reader-position)
                            :movement :looping-forward)
                     (assoc interpreter-state
                            :reader-position (inc reader-position)
                            :movement :moving-forward))
                \] (if (not (= 0 (nth cells cell-pointer)))
                     (assoc interpreter-state
                            :reader-position (dec reader-position)
                            :movement :looping-backward)
                     (assoc interpreter-state
                            :reader-position (inc reader-position)
                            :movement :moving-forward))
                \, (assoc interpreter-state
                          :reader-position (inc reader-position)
                          :cells (assoc cells cell-pointer (.charCodeAt text-input 0))
                          :movement :moving-forward)
                :else (assoc interpreter-state
                             :reader-position (inc reader-position)
                             :movement :moving-forward)))))) ;; Moves reader-position forward if the current character is unknown

(defn interpret [state]
  (let [src (:src (:interpreter-state @state))
        interpreter-state (assoc (:interpreter-state @state) :src src :running true)]
    (go
      (loop [interpreter-state interpreter-state]
        (if (not (nil? (:terminated-due-to interpreter-state)))
          (swap! state assoc :interpreter-state (assoc interpreter-state :running false))
          (do
            (<! (timeout (:delay @state)))
            (swap! state assoc :interpreter-state interpreter-state)
            (let [current-symbol (retrieve-current-symbol interpreter-state)]
              (if (= current-symbol \,)
                (do (swap! state assoc :brainfuck-input-disabled false)
                    (let [text-input (<! input-buffer)]
                      (swap! state assoc :brainfuck-input-disabled true)
                      (recur (step interpreter-state input-buffer current-symbol text-input))))
                (recur (step interpreter-state input-buffer current-symbol nil))))))))))


;; /Interpreter ------------------------------------------------

;; State -------------------------------------------------------

(def initial-interpreter-state {:src ""
                                :reader-position 0
                                :cells (initialize-cells 200)
                                :cell-pointer 50
                                :movement :moving-forward
                                :nested-left-brackets 0
                                :nested-right-brackets 0
                                :printedchars ""
                                :terminated-due-to nil
                                :running false})

(defonce state (r/atom {:sourcecode ""
                        :delay 1
                        :cell-display-width 3
                        :brainfuck-input-disabled true
                        :interpreter-state initial-interpreter-state}))

;; /State ------------------------------------------------------

(defn boxes [cells cell-pointer]
  (let [width (:cell-display-width @state) 
        cells-immediately-before-pointer (drop (- cell-pointer width) (take cell-pointer cells))
        cell-at-pointer (nth cells cell-pointer)
        cells-immediately-after-pointer (take width (drop (+ 1 cell-pointer) cells))
        box-size 35]
    [:div {:style {:width "100%"
                   :display "flex"
                   :justify-content "center"
                   :overflow "hidden"
                   :clip "inherit"}}
     [:div {:style {:display "flex"}} (map #(number-box % "black" box-size) cells-immediately-before-pointer)]
     [:div {:style {:display "flex"}} (number-box cell-at-pointer "darkcyan" box-size)]
     [:div {:style {:display "flex"}} (map #(number-box % "black" box-size) cells-immediately-after-pointer)]]))

(defn display-running-sourcecode []
  [:div {:style {:border "1px solid black"
                 :resize "none"
                 :font-size "2em"
                 :width "100%"
                 :height "100%"
                 :visibility (not (:running (:interpreter-state @state)))}}
   (let [source (:src (:interpreter-state @state))
         position (:reader-position (:interpreter-state @state))]
     [:div {:style {:list-style-type "none"
                    :overflow-y "auto"
                    :width "100%"
                    :height "100%"
                    :word-break "break-all"
                    :word-wrap "break-word"}}
      [:div {:style {:display "inline"
                     :width "100%"}} (take position source)]
      [:div {:style {:background-color "turquoise"
                     :display "inline"
                     :width "100%"}} (str (nth source position))]
      [:div {:style {:background-color "white"
                     :display "inline"
                     :width "100%"}} (drop (+ position 1) source)]])])

(defn display-editable-textbox []
  [:textarea {:style {:border "1px solid black"
                      :resize "none"
                      :word-wrap "break-word"
                      :word-break "break-all"
                      :font-size "2em"
                      :width "100%"
                      :height "100%"
                      :font-family "Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New, monospace"
                      :visibility (not (:running (:interpreter-state @state)))}
              :disabled (:running (:interpreter-state @state))
              :value (:sourcecode @state)
              :on-change #(do
                            (let [new-value (-> % .-target .-value)]
                              (swap! state assoc :sourcecode new-value)))}])

(defn slider [key-in-state range-start range-end label]
  [:div {:style {:float "right"}}
   [:div {:style {:text-align "right"}} label]
   [:div {:style {:display "inline" }} (key-in-state @state)]
   [:div {:style {:display "inline" }}
    [:input {:type "range"
             :min range-start
             :max range-end
             :value (key-in-state @state)
             :on-input #(swap! state assoc key-in-state (-> % .-target .-value))}]]])

(defn blinker-button [] ;;only intended for development
  [:p {:style {:padding-top "10px"}}
   [:button {:type "button"
             :on-click #(swap! state assoc :interpreter-state (assoc (:interpreter-state @state) :running (not (:running (:interpreter-state @state)))))
             }
    "Blink"]])

(defn evaluate-button []
  [:div {:style {:display "inline"}}
   [:button {:type "button"
             :disabled (:running (:interpreter-state @state))
             :on-click #(do (swap! state assoc :interpreter-state initial-interpreter-state)
                            (swap! state assoc :interpreter-state (assoc (:interpreter-state @state) :src (:sourcecode @state)))
                            (interpret state))}
    "Evaluate!"]])

(defn brainfuck-input []
  [:div {:style {:display "inline"
                 :float "right"}}
   [:input.char-input {:type "text"
                       :max-length "1"
                       :style {:width "1em"
                               :text-align "center"}
                       :disabled (:brainfuck-input-disabled @state)}]
   [:input {:type "button"
            :value "Enter character"
            :disabled (:brainfuck-input-disabled @state)
            :on-click #(let [input-char (-> (sel1 ".char-input")
                                            .-value)]
                         (go (>! input-buffer input-char)))
            }]])

(defn sourcecode-box []
  [:div {:type "text"
         :id "sourcecode-box"
         :style {:width "100%"
                 :height "200px"
                 :font-family "Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New, monospace"
                 :border-color "#cccccc" }}
   (if (:running (:interpreter-state @state))
     [display-running-sourcecode]
     [display-editable-textbox])])

(defn sourcecode-repeater []
  [:p {:style {:word-break "break-all"
               :word-wrap "break-word"
               :overflow "auto"
               :font-family "Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New, monospace"
               }} (:sourcecode @state)])

(defn results []
  [:div "Output:"
   [:div {:style {:border "1px solid teal"
                  :text-align "center"
                  :min-height "3em"
                  :word-wrap "break-word"
                  :word-break "break-all"
                  :padding "1em"}}
    [:p (:printedchars (:interpreter-state @state))]]])

(defn printing-example []
  [:div
   [:p "Here is some sample Brainfuck that prints \"derpa\", just to get you started: "]
   [:p "++++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>.+.+++++++++++++.--.---------------."]])

(defn brainfuck-reference []
  [:div "Reference sheet"
   [:br]
   [:table.reference {:style {:border "1px solid teal"
                              :text-align "center"}}
    [:tr [:th "Character"][:th "Meaning"]]
    [:tr [:td ">"] [:td "increment the data pointer (to point to the next cell to the right)."]]
    [:tr [:td "<"] [:td "decrement the data pointer (to point to the next cell to the left)."]]
    [:tr [:td "+"] [:td "increment (increase by one) the byte at the data pointer."]]
    [:tr [:td "-"] [:td "decrement (decrease by one) the byte at the data pointer."]]
    [:tr [:td "."] [:td "output the byte at the data pointer."]]
    [:tr [:td ","] [:td "accept one byte of input, storing its value in the byte at the data pointer."]]
    [:tr [:td "["] [:td "if the byte at the data pointer is zero, then instead of moving the instruction pointer forward to the next command, jump it forward to the command after the matching ] command."]]
    [:tr [:td "]"] [:td "if the byte at the data pointer is nonzero, then instead of moving the instruction pointer forward to the next command, jump it back to the command after the matching [ command."]]
    [:tr  [:td {:col-span 2
                :style {:border "1px solid black"}} [printing-example]]]]])

(defn samples []
  [:div
   [brainfuck-reference]])

(defn project-root []
  [:div#screen {:style {:width "100%"
                        }}
   [:div#left {:style {:float "left"
                       :width "100%"}}]
   [:div#right {:style {:float "right"}}
    [:div {:style {:float "left"}}
     [slider :delay 5 1000 "Delay"]
     [:br]
     [:br]
     [:br]
     [slider :cell-display-width 1 50 "Cells around pointer"]
     [:div {:style {:height "5em"}}]]]
   [:div#center {:style {:width "500px"
                         :margin "0 auto"
                         :font-family "Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif"}}
    [:br]
    [boxes (:cells (:interpreter-state @state)) (:cell-pointer (:interpreter-state @state))]
    [:br]
    [:br]
    [:p "Write your Brainfuck sourcecode here: "]
    [sourcecode-box]
    [:div {:style {:padding-top "10px"}}
     [evaluate-button]
     [brainfuck-input]]
    [:br]
    [:br]
    [results]
    [:br]
    [:br]
    [:br]
    [samples]]
   ])

(defn start []
  (r/render-component
   [project-root]
   (.getElementById js/document "root")))

(start)

(enable-console-print!)

(println "Edits to this text should show up in your developer console. LOL")

(defn on-js-reload []
  ;; optionally touch your app-state to force rerendering depending on
  ;; your application
  (swap! state update-in [:__figwheel_counter] inc))
```

Comment: For a Clojurescript noob, what are the requirements to build it and host it? I find it interesting, but I am very new to clojure and clojurescript.

Comment: Hello Simon, thank you for your interest! I think all you need to do is to have the newest version of Clojure installed as well as Leiningen. Clone the derpanet repository and go to /derpanet in your terminal of choice, then execute `lein figwheel dev`. This will start up the server (and download the dependencies the first time you do it, so it will probably take a while), and when it's fully loaded, the last line should read something like `Prompt will show when figwheel connects to your application`. Then go to [http://localhost:3449/index.html](http://localhost:3449/index.html) :)

Comment: Hello again @SimonForsberg :) I've managed to get the app hosted! It required adding a backend, but the build and host process is still simple, provided that you have all the right stuff installed; clone, `cd derpanet`, `lein figwheel`. But you can view the app at https://derpanet.herokuapp.com/ . It's best in Firefox, wonky but workable in Chrome, and while non-essential functionality (the sliders) is broken in IE, the interpreting functionality still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code mostly looks fine to me, except for the central `step` function, as you pointed out. Here is my suggested refactor with some notes.

### `update` and DRY

By using `update` in addition to `assoc` and factoring out some repetitive parts, you can rearrange `step` like this:

```clj
(defn step [interpreter-state input-chan current-symbol text-input]
  (cond 
    (out-of-upper-sourcecode-bounds? interpreter-state)
    (assoc interpreter-state :terminated-due-to :reached-upper-sourcecode-bounds)

    (looping? interpreter-state)
    (step-loop interpreter-state current-symbol)

    :else
    (let [{:keys [cells cell-pointer]} interpreter-state
          pointed-cell (nth cells cell-pointer)]
      (condp = current-symbol
        \[ (-> interpreter-state
               (update :reader-position inc)
               (assoc :movement (if (zero? pointed-cell)
                                  :looping-forward
                                  :moving-forward)))

        \] (if-not (zero? pointed-cell)
             (-> interpreter-state
                 (update :reader-position dec)
                 (assoc :movement :looping-backward))
             (-> interpreter-state
                 (update :reader-position inc)
                 (assoc :movement :moving-forward)))

        :else (let [actions {\+ [[:cells cell-pointer] inc]
                             \- [[:cells cell-pointer] dec]
                             \> [[:cell-pointer] inc]
                             \< [[:cell-pointer] dec]
                             \. [[:printedchars] #(apply str % (char pointed-cell))]
                             \, [[:cells cell-pointer] (fn [_] (.charCodeAt text-input 0))]}]
                (-> (if-let [[path f] (actions current-symbol)]
                      (update-in interpreter-state path f)
                      interpreter-state)  ; If current char is unknown, just continue
                    (update :reader-position inc)
                    (assoc :movement :moving-forward)))))))
```

which is still sufficiently unwieldy but an improvement, I think.

- I've placed the `cond`-case results underneath their case to avoid getting indented so much.
- I've also used a lookup table of update actions for the `+`, `-`, etc. symbols, so it's easier to see what is different between each one.
- `(if-not` instead of `(if (not`
- `(zero?` instead of `(= 0` (debatable)

Using `update` instead of `assoc` cuts down on the number of values you need to extract via key-destructuring, because you no longer need to know the actual values of those keys -- just pass the update-fn to `update`.

### Looping

I've pulled most of the looping logic out into a separate function, to make `step` shorter. You can decide whether this `step-loop'` abstraction is any more readable than your current version, but I do think that `step-loop` overall should be its own function.

```clj
(def looping? (some-fn looping-forward? looping-backward?))

(defn step-loop [interpreter-state current-symbol]
  {:pre [(looping? interpreter-state)]}
  (let [step-loop' (fn [continue-looping open-char open-char-key close-char close-char-key]
                    (condp = current-symbol
                      close-char (if (brackets-balanced? interpreter-state)
                                   (-> interpreter-state
                                       (update :reader-position inc)
                                       (assoc :movement :moving-forward
                                              :nested-left-brackets 0
                                              :nested-right-brackets 0))
                                   (-> interpreter-state
                                       (update close-char-key inc)
                                       continue-looping))
                      open-char (-> interpreter-state
                                    (update open-char-key inc)
                                    continue-looping)
                      :else (continue-looping interpreter-state)))]
    (if (looping-forward? interpreter-state)
      (step-loop' #(-> %
                      (update :reader-position inc)
                      (assoc :movement :looping-forward))
                 \[ :nested-left-brackets \] :nested-right-brackets)

      (step-loop' #(-> %
                      (update :reader-position dec)
                      (assoc :movement :looping-backward))
                 \] :nested-right-brackets \[ :nested-left-brackets))))
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough workover :) There are some good low-hanging ideas here that I will definitely use: `update`, `if-not`, `zero`. Separating the looping functionality out into a separate function also seems like a very good structural decision, I think I will do that, too. The `actions` lookup table seems like a clever idea - at first, I thought it add a layer of misdirection, but I'm warming up to it. My inexperience in reading Clojure is probably at play, here. All in all, I think your suggestions help greatly in understanding what's going on.

Comment: I think there's still work to be done, and all of these suggestions are helping me onto the right path. The biggest (and persisting) problem, I think, is achieving source code of a quality where the reader can quickly gather what is going on without reading through the lot of it. In my case, I think/hope that this can be achieved by extracting smaller functions, so that the `step` function and other central functions express the control structure of the interpreter and not the read/write details, which are left to the "leaf" functions.